# PHP Session variables not staying

Tags: php, session, save

So, I have this RPG game I've been working on using PHP for the hell of it. I've been trying to get some sessions to work for quite some time to save my variables over various pages, which, obviously, is what they're intended for. Here's the code related to my problem from my page:

Line 1: `<?php session_start(); ?>`

This part is just determining the results from the form the user fills out to "create their character"

```
if ($_GET["race"]=="Human"){
$_SESSION["race"] = "Human";
$_SESSION["raceadj"] = "Human";
$_SESSION['racestrengthbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['raceendurancebonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['raceintellectbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['racewillpowerbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['raceluckbonus'] = 0;
```

and for the class

```
if ($_GET["career"]=="Knight"){
$_SESSION["career"] = "Knight";
$_SESSION['classstrengthbonus'] = 10;
$_SESSION['classendurancebonus'] = 10;
$_SESSION['classintellectbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['classwillpowerbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['classluckbonus'] = 0;
$_SESSION['RightHand'] = "Iron Sword";
$_SESSION['LeftHand'] = "Wooden Shield";
$_SESSION['Armor'] = "Iron Armor";
```

Now here's the code where all of that is being used.

```
<?PHP
echo "<div class=\"playerstats\" align=\"center\"><span class=\"playername\">".$_GET["name"]."</span><br><span class=\"redtext\">".$_SESSION["race"]." - ".$_SESSION['career']." - ".$_SESSION["health"]." HP - ".$_SESSION["gold"]." Gold</div>
<div style=\"float:left\"><span class=\"redtext\">Strength: </span>".$_SESSION["strength"]."<br>
<span class=\"redtext\">Endurance: </span>".$_SESSION["endurance"]."<br>
<span class=\"redtext\">Intellect: </span>".$_SESSION["intellect"]."<br>
<span class=\"redtext\">Willpower: </span>".$_SESSION["willpower"]."<br>
<span class=\"redtext\">Luck: </span>".$_SESSION["luck"]."<br></div>";

echo "<div class=\"equipment\"><span class=\"hover right\">".$_SESSION["RightHand"]."</span><span class=\"redtext\"> - Right Hand</span><br>
<span class=\"hover left\">".$_SESSION['LeftHand']."</span><span class=\"redtext\"> - Left Hand</span><br>
<span class=\"hover\">".$_SESSION['Armor']."</span><span class=\"redtext\"> - Armor</span><br></div>"; ?>
```

When I first load up this page, everything displays correctly. The name, race, etc all displays what the user put in their form, but if the user uses any of the actions on the page (which are simply forms that display the results on this same page) then it doesn't save the variables and goes right to the "else" results of both race and class, with no name saved. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: you can debug if session is working properly, make two testing page, one session_start(); $_SESSION['test']="test";  then second page, session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);   see if test there after you run first page, then you run second page.  if it is displayed, then maybe there is issue with the form or you forgot to add session_start before any input.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `session_start` at the beginning and in every page you wanted to use your session vars. If you forget to declare session_start at the beginning, the session is forgotten in limbo.

EDIT:

page1.php

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['bar'] = "SAVED SESSION"; ?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['bar']; ?> // outputs 'SAVED SESSION'
```

page3.php

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['bar']; ?> // outputs ''; session is forgotten
```

EDIT: I recreated part of your test game here: http://www.huinda.com/test/ sessions do work, you only handle it incorrectly, so they are either erased accidentally or being set to null accidentally.

Comment: Well, I'm only working with one page now. The form on this page where the sessions are being worked with is sent to this same page to work with the information being sent to it. After sending the information, all the sessions seem to be unset.

Comment: Seems your form is not being set/handled correctly. Show me the code in your form.

Comment: <form action="questselection.php" method="GET">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="radio" name="career" value="Knight">
 <input type="radio" name="career" value="Rogue">
 <input type="radio" name="career" value="Wizard">
 <input type="radio" name="career" value="Battlemage">
 <input type="radio" name="career" value="Assassin">
 <input type="radio" name="race" value="Human">
 <input type="radio" name="race" value="Elf">
 <input type="radio" name="race" value="Lycan">
 <input type="radio" name="race" value="Orc">
 <input type="submit" value="Begin your Quest!">
</form>

Comment: @Zenox I have recreated your test game here: http://www.huinda.com/test/ ... so tell me what seems to be the problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have 'race' and 'career' in $_GET once your form was submitted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean haha. This RPG game was created as a way to teach me PHP. On the original page, I have this to start the form: `<form action="questselection.php" method="GET">` so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for form method=POST and so $_GET[var] will not find variable.  Although you said first view it appears correctly so seems the values were retrieved.

I suspect you need to configure your session store in php.ini file and restart your web server.

session.save_path

- SEE: http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

Make sure it's a writeable directory by the web server.